# force close when I try to edit an Edit Text

Tags: android

I would like to edit the details in my EditTextBox(fcon/fuel consumption).
However,
when I try to edit it,
it will give me force close error.

I wonder why is that so?
can someone help me out?

updateAnddelete.java

```
public class updateAnddelete extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        // TableLayout tablelayout_Log = null;
       private Button deleteButton;
       private Button updateButton;
       private Button cancelButton;
       // Button searchButton = null;
       private    static EditText dateEdit; 
       private    EditText priceEdit;
       private    EditText pumpEdit;
       private  TextView costView;
       private   EditText odometerEdit;
       private   TextView fconView;
       private     TextWatcher textWatcher;
     private     String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
      private     String  odmEditStr = "";
       private     String lastOdm = "";
       private String bundleDate;
        private String bundlePrice;
        private String bundlePump;
        private String bundleCost;
        private String bundleOdometer;
        private String bundleFcon;


        private String dateEditTextValue;
        private String priceEditTextValue;
        private String pumpEditTextValue;
        private String costTextViewValue;
        private String odometerEditTextValue;
        private String fconTextViewValue;
    double result;
    double resultCon;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;




        public boolean isNumeric(String str)
        {
            return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
            dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
            priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
            pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);
            odometerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.odometer);
            fconView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fcon);

            cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBTN);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBTN);
            updateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBTN);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Bundle takeBundledData = getIntent().getExtras();

            // First we need to get the bundle data that pass from the UndergraduateListActivity
            bundleDate = takeBundledData.getString("clickedDate");
            bundlePrice = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPrice");
            bundlePump = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPump");
            bundleCost = takeBundledData.getString("clickedCost");
            bundleOdometer = takeBundledData.getString("clickedOdometer");
            bundleFcon = takeBundledData.getString("clickedFCon");

            // Set the values that we extracted from the Bundle in the EditText fields
            dateEdit.setText(bundleDate);
            priceEdit.setText(bundlePrice);
            pumpEdit.setText(bundlePump);
            costView.setText(bundleCost);
            odometerEdit.setText(bundleOdometer);
            fconView.setText(bundleFcon);






            dateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                }
            });


               priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                           priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                           pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                      if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
                        result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                        costView.setText(" "+result);
                      }

                   }
               });

               pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                          {
                            result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                            costView.setText(" "+result);
                          }

                   }
               });







               odometerEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }



                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it

                       if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                           odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                      if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null) && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
                         {

                           resultCon = Double.parseDouble(odmEditStr) / Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                           fconView.setText(" "+resultCon);
                         }

                   }
               });

        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // We need to update or delete details which is in the EditText fields after user edit the values
            // These values are the ContentValues that we are going to use in future
            dateEditTextValue = dateEdit.getText().toString();
            priceEditTextValue = priceEdit.getText().toString();
            pumpEditTextValue = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
            costTextViewValue = costView.getText().toString();
            odometerEditTextValue = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
            fconTextViewValue = fconView.getText().toString();
            // It is easy to set values to the POJO class and pass the class instance to the updateUgraduateDetails() method
            fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojo = new fuelLogPojo();

            fuelLogPojo.setdate(bundleDate);
            fuelLogPojo.setprice(bundlePrice);
            fuelLogPojo.setpump(bundlePump);
            fuelLogPojo.setcost(bundleCost);
            fuelLogPojo.setodometer(bundleOdometer);
            fuelLogPojo.setfcon(bundleFcon);




            if(v.getId() == R.id.cancelBTN){
                finish();
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.updateBTN){
                updateLog(fuelLogPojo);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.deleteBTN){
                deleteLog(fuelLogPojo);
            }
        }



        private void deleteLog(fuelLogPojo deletefuelLogPojo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] whereClauseArgument = new String[1];
            whereClauseArgument[0] = deletefuelLogPojo.getdate();

            // Only difference between UPDATE and DELETE is
            //DELETE does not have ContentValues part
            sqliteDatabase.delete(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE+"=?", whereClauseArgument);

            sqliteDatabase.close();
            finish();           


        }

        private void updateLog(fuelLogPojo updatefuelLogPojo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            // ContentValues class is used to store a set of values
            //It is like name-value pairs
            // "value" part contains the values that we are going to UPDATE
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE, dateEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE, priceEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL, pumpEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST, costTextViewValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM, odometerEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON, fconTextViewValue);

            // If we are using multiple whereClauseArguments, array size should have to change
            String[] whereClauseArgument = new String[1];
            whereClauseArgument[0] = updatefuelLogPojo.getdate();

            System.out.println("whereClauseArgument[0] is :" + whereClauseArgument[0]);

            /**
             * This is the normal SQL query for UPDATE
            UPDATE table_name
            SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
            WHERE some_column=some_value
            */      

            sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, contentValues, AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE+"=?", whereClauseArgument);
            // For two whereClauseArguments
            //sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, contentValues, BaseColumns._ID+"=? AND name=?", whereClauseArgument);

            sqliteDatabase.close();
            finish();
        }       





        public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

            public EditText editText;
            DatePicker dpResult;

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            dateEdit.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                    + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
            // set selected date into datepicker also
    }}}
```

logcat:

```
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.example.fuellogproject.updateAnddelete$4.afterTextChanged(updateAnddelete.java:210)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7562)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9383)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:212)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:356)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5647)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5459)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2705)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7263)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1413)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2118)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1470)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2426)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2045)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3924)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3858)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3415)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4528)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4506)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3152)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-24 18:28:46.033: E/AndroidRuntime(8694):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting exception because you initialized variables as `String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";` so, values are not getting changed when edittext are empty.

So you need to initialize variables as

```
 private String priceEditStr ="0.0",pumpEditStr="0.0";
```

And need to replace `afterTextChanged()` as below

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (! android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(priceEdit.getText())) {
        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    if (! android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(pumpEdit.getText())) {
        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
    costView.setText(" "+result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've 2 afterTextChanged, which one are you talking about?

Comment: @Chloe Ohh that was for `priceEdit`. You can do same like for others. If you have any confusion ask me..

Comment: @Chloe What is the error? And this is not a good behavior to unaccepted the answer... because given answer is correct. You are getting another error, not for this code. Show me your code..

Comment: nono , at first I thought it's working, but actually it's not.

Comment: is the error is parse exception?? Did you changed your all occurrence of afterTextChanged?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46013/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-chloe)

Answer (score 2):

I think Here you got error :

```
result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);
```

**Reason** :
your `priceEditStr` or `pumpEditStris` null.

Check for null like..

```
if(priceEditStr.length()>0 && pumpEditStr.length()>0){
 result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);       
}
```

Let me know its working or not.

Comment: I think the error lies here

   if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: because, it's when I select on THAT EDIT TEXT, then it will force close.
However, when I select on price or pump EDIT TEXT ,no force close is shown

Comment: I don't think this solution is correct. If priceEditStr or pumpEditStr is null, then priceEditStr.length will cause a NullPointerException. Moreover, the proposed solution will not solve a NumberFormatException because it is not checking if the value of priceEditStr and pumpEditStr is a properly formatted number.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is very self-explanatory :

> NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

This means that the value you are trying to parse into a Double is not a properly formatted number. In this case, you are trying to parse an empty String into a number. You should put a try/catch clause around your parsing calls, and limit the EditText to valid number, using the following attribute in the declaration of your EditText in your xml :

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```